# removing min from list and converting to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

This is my code to gather list of scores of students. The program will remove the min of list before averaging the scores. But, after removing the min and averaging it. The computation still computes together with the removed min. How can I fix that?

```
def student_scores():

    students_scores = []
    scores = ''
    while scores != 0:
            scores = int(input('Enter your scores or 0 to end: '))
            if scores != 0:
                students_scores.append(scores)
    return students_scores



def compute_total(gradelist):

    tot = int()
    for num in gradelist:
        tot += num
    return tot

def drop_lowest(scores):

    scores.remove(min(scores))
    scores2 = []
    scores2.extend(scores)

    least = tuple(scores2)

    return least

def get_mean(lowest,scores):

    mean = lowest / len(scores)
    return mean


def main():

    scores = student_scores()
    total = compute_total(scores)
    lowest = drop_lowest(scores)
    average = get_mean(total,scores)


    print('Scores with lowest score is now removed', lowest)
    print('The mean is: ', average)

main()
```

Comment: you dont use the scores with removed minimum to calculate the average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code first gets a list of scores, finds the sum of all of those scores, makes a list without the lowest score, and then computes the total of all the original grades / the number of original scores.

If you want to find the mean of scores without taking the lowest score change your main to:

```
scores = student_scores()
lowest = drop_lowest(scores)
total = compute_total(lowest)
average = get_mean(total,lowest)
```

which will give you the mean of all the scores without the lowest score.

Hope that helps!